# Best practice to change the text of a div in html with button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

I'm looking for the best practice to change the text content of an element on my website's page.

I actually have 4 buttons (I aim for 9). Each button should be able to change the text depending on which one is clicked last.

Here is the html part

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-12">
  <button class="button-pltfrm button-ptf-1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button-pltfrm button-ptf-2">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button-pltfrm button-ptf-3">Button 3</button>
  <button class="button-pltfrm button-ptf-4">Button 4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 pltfrm-distrib-wrapper">
    <div>
      <p id="change-txt" class="horaire-distrib">
        I wanna change this text to something else
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've actually tried to way to do it. First one is by using jquery :

```js
$(".button-pltfrm").click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass("button-ptf-1"))
        $("#change-txt").text("This text belong to the first button");
    if($(this).hasClass("button-ptf-2"))
        $("#change-txt").text("This text belong to the second button");
    if($(this).hasClass("button-ptf-3"))
        $("#change-txt").text("This text belong to the third button");
    if($(this).hasClass("button-ptf-4"))
        $("#change-txt").text("This text belong to the fourth button");
  });
```

Here is a link with a jsfiddle doing the exact same thing.
[1]https://jsfiddle.net/4m0z8srb/20/

I find the fact that I have to do a test for each tag of each button rather unclear. It also need to modify javascript file each time I want to add a button.

I tried another version, who seems to be a bit more clear. In this one, the buttons are the ones calling a function in raw JavaScript. They call the function with the argument that the text is going to change into. Here is the html code (I had to modify it) :

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-12">
  <button onclick="chng_txt('This text belong to the first button')" class="button-pltfrm">Button 1</button>
  <button onclick="chng_txt('This text belong to the second button')" class="button-pltfrm">Button 2</button>
  <button onclick="chng_txt('This text belong to the third button')" class="button-pltfrm">Button 3</button>
  <button onclick="chng_txt('This text belong to the fourth button')" class="button-pltfrm">Button 4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 pltfrm-distrib-wrapper">
    <div>
      <p id="change-txt" class="horaire-distrib">
        I wanna change this text to something else
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
var cameleon_txt = document.getElementById("change-txt");
function chng_txt(text)
{
    cameleon_txt.innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

I also added a link to an other jsfiddle with this implementation.
[2]https://jsfiddle.net/e8x45chn/7/.
In this version, I really do not like the fact that the text is inside the parameter of the function called by onclick. It makes the line really long if I want to put a bigger text.

As you can see, I tried two options with JS that are working but I would like to know if there is a good way to do it maybe with CSS in the idea that the text might need to be translated later on.

I am looking for the best practice and ideally the one that is going to be clearer in case someone has to work on the code after me.

Comment: `$(".col-12").on("click", ".button-pltfrm", function (event) {` then `this` is that button that was clicked.  Which could hold the text or a reference to use as a data attribute. Related https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation

Answer (score 3):

You can put your text into `data-text` attribute:

```js
$('.button-list').on('click', 'button', e =>  
  $('#change-txt').text($(e.target).data('text'))
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 button-list">
  <button data-text="Selected 1">Button 1</button>
  <button data-text="Selected 2">Button 2</button>
  <button data-text="Selected 3">Button 3</button>
  <button data-text="Selected 4">Button 4</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 pltfrm-distrib-wrapper">
    <div>
      <p id="change-txt" class="horaire-distrib">
        I wanna change this text to something else
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I was about to add a second example to my answer showing this. It's preferrable to an onclick attribute because it keeps concerns separate.

Answer (score 2):

I like using an array or object as a button/text map, using button index as the key. This keeps your data out of your markup (and somewhat isolated within your script for easier maintenance--it could come from another file, for example).

Here I'm using a simple array. You could use an object instead to correlate indexes or IDs to the text values.

Here's a [helpful resource](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) as you (now or eventually) transition away from jQuery, which I consider an awesome but increasingly unnecessary library.

```js
const textMap = ['text one', 'text two', 'text three', 'text four'];

document.querySelectorAll('.button-pltfrm').forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = () => {
    const index = [...el.parentNode.children].indexOf(el);
    chng_txt(textMap[index]);
  };
});

function chng_txt(text) {
  document.querySelector('#change-txt').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="button-pltfrm">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button-pltfrm">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button-pltfrm">Button 3</button>
    <button class="button-pltfrm">Button 4</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 pltfrm-distrib-wrapper">
    <div>
      <p id="change-txt" class="horaire-distrib">
        I wanna change this text to something else
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```